# development at Magento-CE

Tags: php, oop, magento

Am a beginner to magento-CE, I tried to create a simple "hello world" module as per given at  their knowledge base site. But I have no idea how to see the changes/update created. It's mentioned in their site to check for any changes made, you need to access URL http://example.com/helloworld/index/index , since I named the packagename as helloworld, action controller as "IndexContrller" and the action controller method as "indexAction". If am supposed to access the back end of magento-CE through localhost, why am I supposed to check it through http address ? If am upposed to do so, then please tell me where am getting it wrong and mention the proper method.

Comment: Could you please post your config.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see your hello world in the frontend you need to declare a frontend router in your config.xml

Like this.

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <ebank>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ihrcms_Ebank</module>
                    <frontName>ebank</frontName>
                </args>
            </ebank>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
```

Important now is the frontname. Here we have ebank.
So you can call

```
http://localhost:80/myshop/ebank/
```

If you call it like this Magento will internally translate it to

```
http://localhost:80/myshop/ebank/index/index
```

The first index means that Magento will look for an ActionController in your controllers folder that is called IndexController.
The second index means that Magento will look for a function in the ActionController that is called indexAction.

So with this knowledge you can do some other stuff like this.
Lets asume we have a payment provider where we wanna pay sth.

```
http://localhost:80/myshop/ebank/payment/pay
```

So in this case you have to declare a PaymentController under controllers that implements a payAction method.

Comment: can you please tel me what is "myshop" indicate in http://localhost:80/myshop/ebank/payment/pay